# macOS Terminal autocompletion suggestion

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm looking at a video and the Terminal in **WebStorm** looks like this

[image]

As you can see there is an autocompletion suggestion while he's writing the command. Any clue on how to get this feature?

Here's the video: [Creating Demo APIs with json-server](https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-creating-demo-apis-with-json-server)

To clarify: You see the red part is what the user typed and the gray is the suggestion. I would like to have the suggestion.

Comment: Normally you can get auto-complete when you press tab-key. I Don't know if this also works in webstorm

Comment: yes it does, but the feature is actually kinda different. You see the red part is what the user typed and the gray is the suggestion

Comment: Perhaps this is what you need? https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/command-line-tools-in-phpstorm/

Comment: @Jules, How does PhpStorm, in your last comment, provide the IDE Terminal auto-completion feature to macOS Terminal? All your suggesting is a different IDE then the one show in the OP and that's not what steo is asking for.

Comment: @user3439894 oops my bad.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but https://github.com/cantino/mcfly is a popular recent addition to the autocompletion scene.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the zsh shell with the zsh-autosuggestions plugin.

- https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

This screenshot looks very much like the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/). This is an alternative shell to bash. One of its core features is smart auto-completion.

Alternatively you could use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install auto-completion for bash:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

You will have to press <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the command you are currently typing. Press twice for all options -- if no unique completion exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a somehow similar behavior by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in Terminal. The command invokes a reverse search in your bash history file.

Example:

After entering `d` and hitting the shortcut, I get `diskutil info disk1s2`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Manter](https://github.com/iondodon/manter). This is an open-source terminal that has autocomplete suggestions like an IDE.

Comment: Bash and Zsh (default shell starting with Catalina) both already have autocomplete built in and there are shell extensions that further enhance this.  What benefit would this obscure shell bring to the table that Terminal or iTerm don’t already bring?

Answer (score -1):

I use https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto. It supports color themes and auto completion

Answer (score -2):

For Mac use the following setup
https://fig.io/

Comment: Answers should be more than just links. What does the tool do, how does it solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/320121)